# Verify jwt in react(client side)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, jwt

How do i verify and authenticate jwt token stored in session on client side with react?
I write an auth function that checks whether jwt is valid or not

```
const checkauthjwtexpiry = store => {
var jwt = sessionStorage.getItem("token");

 if (!jwt) {
  return false;
 }
 try {
  var jwt = sessionStorage.getItem("token");
  var jwtdecode = jwt_decode(jwt);

  var { exp } = jwtdecode;
  var datainseconds = new Date().getTime() / 1000;
  if (exp < datainseconds) {
  store.dispatch(
    info(
      notification("Token Invalid,please login again", "error")
    )
  );
  sessionStorage.removeItem("token");
  return false;
 }
} catch (e) {
return false;
}
return true;
};
```

---

The question is that,if i change or modify some jwt in session storage,the `jwt_decode` is not able to verify it, and i still remain an authenticated user after the jwt gets changed. Please help what to do

Comment: what do you mean by "i still remain an authenticated user"? does the resource provider accept a JWT that you modify on the client-side??? is the token signed and is it signed with an asymmetric key?

Comment: Everything on client side can be viewed by anyone who knows how to view source code. you shouldn't be verifying/authenticating jwt on the client side at all. It should be done on server side

Comment: @JacobGoh it can be done safely if the signing is done with an asymmetric key pair. The client only needs the public key to verify, so no secret is exposed.

Comment: @Touffy oh is it. Thanks for the info. gotta study it

Comment: @Touffy i mean that from devtool i change the jwt token to invalid token,and then refresh the page, but it still remain on dashboard page not getting redirect to login page

Comment: @tapandave if your verification code doesn't check the signature or ask the server, then it is perfectly normal that you cannot detect the token is invalid.

Comment: @JacobGoh the standard [JWA signing algorithms](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7518#section-3) that use a private/public key pair are RSASSA with SHA and ECDSA with SHA. (edit: ECDSA *is* supported by Web Crypto as well as RSASSA, it's EC encryption that isn't supported)

Comment: @Touffy so can i use jsonwebtoken to verify and then redirect to login,or is there any to prevent that if someone changes the token, he should not be able to stay in authenticated route

Comment: You can't be absolutely sure on the client-side anyway (the user could change your JavaScript to skip the verification, after all). A reasonable step would be to check the token signature after fetching the public key from the authorisation server. If you are using one of the algorithms I mentioned above, I can shamelessly recommend my own [webtoken-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webtoken-client) for that ;)

Comment: @Touffy ok thanks....